# Start and end date of a current month

Tags: java, date-manipulation

I need the start date and the end date of the current month in Java. When the JSP page is loaded with the current month it should automatically calculate the start and end date of that month. It should be irrespective of the year and month. That is some month has 31 days or 30 days or 28 days. This should satisfy for a leap year too. Can you help me out with that?

For example if I select month May in a list box I need starting date that is 1 and end date that is 31.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There you go:

```
public Pair<Date, Date> getDateRange() {
    Date begining, end;

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToBeginningOfDay(calendar);
        begining = calendar.getTime();
    }

    {
        Calendar calendar = getCalendarForNow();
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,
                calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        setTimeToEndofDay(calendar);
        end = calendar.getTime();
    }

    return Pair.of(begining, end);
}

private static Calendar getCalendarForNow() {
    Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());
    return calendar;
}

private static void setTimeToBeginningOfDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
}

private static void setTimeToEndofDay(Calendar calendar) {
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
}
```

PS: `Pair` class is simply a pair of two values.

Comment: This is good, but Pair is a terrible abstraction for a date range. Creating a real entity called DateRange would be much better as it would give you a place to add logic.

Comment: I agree. I wrote this just as an example.

Answer (score 35):

If you have the option, you'd better avoid the horrid Java Date API, and use instead [Jodatime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html) (or equivalently the Java 8 `java.time.*` API). Here is an example:

```
LocalDate monthBegin = new LocalDate().withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate monthEnd = new LocalDate().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
```

Comment: Now, with java 8 you can do this with java time: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html

Comment: You can try this:  `LocalDate monthBegin = LocalDate.now().withDayOfMonth(1);
        LocalDate monthEnd = LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);`

Comment: Replace `new LocalDate()` with `LocalDate.now()`

Answer (score 18):

Try LocalDate from Java 8:

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println("First day: " + today.withDayOfMonth(1));
System.out.println("Last day: " + today.withDayOfMonth(today.lengthOfMonth()));
```

Answer (score 9):

> Simple and Best, Try this One

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            Date monthFirstDay = calendar.getTime();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            Date monthLastDay = calendar.getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String startDateStr = df.format(monthFirstDay);
        String endDateStr = df.format(monthLastDay);

        Log.e("DateFirstLast",startDateStr+" "+endDateStr);
```

Comment: I beg to differ. It’s best to avoid the classes `Calendar`, `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`. They are poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See for example the much better and also simpler answer [by aianitro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40276266/5772882).

Answer (score 5):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = 1;
    c.set(year, month, day);
    int numOfDaysInMonth = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    System.out.println("First Day of month: " + c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numOfDaysInMonth-1);
    System.out.println("Last Day of month: " + c.getTime());
```

Comment: As there are multiple other answers and even an accepted one, you should provide a bit of reasoning, what distinguishes your answer from the others.

Answer (score 4):

With the [date4j](http://www.date4j.net) library :

```
dt.getStartOfMonth();
dt.getEndOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this Code

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int yearpart = 2010;
int monthPart = 11;
int dateDay = 1;
calendar.set(yearpart, monthPart, dateDay);
int numOfDaysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Number of Days: " + numOfDaysInMonth);
System.out.println("First Day of month: " + calendar.getTime());
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, numOfDaysInMonth-1);
System.out.println("Last Day of month: " + calendar.getTime());
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

if you have `java.time.YearMonth` you can do:

```
YearMonth startYearMonth = YearMonth.now();
java.time.LocalDate startOfMonthDate = startYearMonth.atDay(1);    
java.time.LocalDate endOfMonthDate   = startYearMonth.atEndOfMonth();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date begining, ending;
Calendar calendar_start =BusinessUnitUtility.getCalendarForNow();
  calendar_start.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar_start.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
  begining = calendar_start.getTime();
  String start= DateDifference.dateToString(begining,"dd-MMM-yyyy");//sdf.format(begining);


   //            for End Date of month
  Calendar calendar_end = BusinessUnitUtility.getCalendarForNow();
  calendar_end.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,calendar_end.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
      ending = calendar_end.getTime();
      String end=DateDifference.dateToString(ending,"dd-MMM-yyyy");//or sdf.format(end);

enter code here



public static Calendar getCalendarForNow() {
        Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        return calendar;
    }
```

Comment: this code will be help to getting Start Date and Ending date of the Current month

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8+, below method will given current month first & last dates as LocalDate instances.

```
public static LocalDate getCurrentMonthFirstDate() {
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).withDayOfMonth(1);
}

public static LocalDate getCurrentMonthLastDate() {
    return LocalDate.ofEpochDay(System.currentTimeMillis() / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ).plusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1).minusDays(1);
}
```

*Side note: Using `LocalDate.ofEpochDay(...)` instead of `LocalDate.now()` gives much improved performance. Also, using the millis-in-a-day expression instead of the end value, which is `86400000` is performing better. I initially thought the latter would perform better than the the expression :P*

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("First day: " + 
today.withDayOfMonth(1));
        System.out.println("Last day: " + today.withDayOfMonth(today.lengthOfMonth()))
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add text to your code answer to enable everybody else to follow you? Thank you!

Comment: @Mike_H I give you a write answer for this code , please execute this code on your text editor and run your answer is Fast Day: 2019-6-01       Second Day: 2019-06-30   Thank you young coder, Hope you understand

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it as below:

```
public void FirstAndLastDate() {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd");
    //start date of month
    calendarStart = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarStart.set(Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")).format(new Date().getTime()))
            , Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("MM")).format(new Date().getTime()))
            , Calendar.getInstance().getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    //End Date of month
    calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarEnd.set(Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy")).format(new Date().getTime()))
            , Integer.parseInt((new SimpleDateFormat("MM")).format(new Date().getTime()))
            , Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    Toast.makeText(this, sdf.format(calendarStart.getTime()) + "\n" + sdf.format(calendarEnd.getTime()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. And a tip: Code only answers are seldom really helpful. It’s from the explanations that we all learn in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

**A very simple step to get the first day and last day of the month:**

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    
    // Get the current date
    Date today = calendar.getTime();
    
    
    // Setting the first day of month
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date firstDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();

    // Move to next month  
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
    // setting the 1st day of the month
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    // Move a day back from the date
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    Date lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getTime();

    // Formatting the date  
    DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-YY");

    String todayStr = sdf.format(today);
    String firstDayOfMonthStr = sdf.format(firstDayOfMonth);
    String lastDayOfMonthStr = sdf.format(lastDayOfMonth);
    
    System.out.println("Today            : " + todayStr);
    System.out.println("Fist Day of Month: "+firstDayOfMonthStr);
    System.out.println("Last Day of Month: "+lastDayOfMonthStr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Making it more modular, you can have one main function that calculates startDate or EndDate and than you can have individual methods to `getMonthStartDate`, `getMonthEndDate` and to `getMonthStartEndDate`. Use methods as per your requirement.

```
public static String getMonthStartEndDate(){
    String start = getMonthDate("START");
    String end = getMonthDate("END");
    String result = start + " to " + end;
    return result;
}

public static String getMonthStartDate(){
    String start = getMonthDate("START");
    return start;
}

public static String getMonthEndDate(){
    String end = getMonthDate("END");
    return end;
}

/**
 * @param filter 
 * START for start date of month e.g.  Nov 01, 2013
 * END for end date of month e.g.  Nov 30, 2013
 * @return
 */
public static String getMonthDate(String filter){
            String MMM_DD_COMMA_YYYY       = "MMM dd, yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(MMM_DD_COMMA_YYYY);
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));
    sdf.format(GregorianCalendar.getInstance().getTime());

    Calendar cal =  GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    int date = cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DATE);
    if("END".equalsIgnoreCase(filter)){
        date = cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE);
    }
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
    String result =  sdf.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(" " + result  );

    return result;
}
```