# Get the week start and end date given a current date and week start

Tags: java, date, jodatime

If possible I would prefer a joda or non-joda solution for the scenario below

Lets say if my week starts on 02/05/2012 and the given current date is 02/22/2011. I need to calculate the week start and end date for the given current date. So my solution should have the week start as 02/19 and week ends at 02/25.
For simplicity, I have set my week start here as 02/05/2011 but it could be any day potentially and my week always has 7 days.

My existing code is below but doesnt seem to work as expected.

```
public Interval getWeekInterval(Date calendarStartDate, Date date)
{
    Calendar sDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    sDate.setTime(getMidnightDate(calendarStartDate));

    Calendar eDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    eDate.setTime(date);

    Calendar weekStartDate = (Calendar) sDate.clone();
    logger.debug("Date:" + sDate.getTime());
    while (sDate.before(eDate)) {
        weekStartDate = sDate;
        sDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH, 1);
    }

    return new Interval(weekStartDate.getTime(), sDate.getTime());
}
```

Comment: What you are expecting and what you got?

Comment: OK, I called getWeekInterval("02/05/2012", "02/11/2012"). I expected 02/05-02/12 but I got 02/12-02/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (pseudo-code):

```
// How many days gone after reference date (a known week-start date)
daysGone  = today - referenceDate;

// A new week starts after each 7 days
dayOfWeek = daysGone % 7;

// Now, we know today is which day of the week.
// We can find start & end days of this week with ease
weekStart = today - dayOfWeek;
weekEnd   = weekStart + 6;
```

Now, we can **shorten** all of this to two lines:

```
weekStart = today - ((today - referenceDate) % 7);
weekEnd   = weekStart + 6;
```

**Note that** we subtracted date values like integers to show algorithm. You have to write your java code properly.

Comment: Thanks for the pseudocode. I managed to find a Ok working solution using Joda Time

Answer (score 10):

## Defining A Week

If you are using date-time objects, you should define a week as up to but not including the first moment of the day after the end of week. As seen in this diagram.

[image: Timeline showing ( >= start of day 1 ) and ( < start of day 8 )]

This approach is known as **Half-Open**. This approach is commonly used for working with spans of time.

The reason is because, logically, that last moment of the day before the new day is infinitely divisible as a fraction of a second. You may think that using ".999" would handle that for milliseconds, but then you'd mistaken when writing for the new java.time.* classes in Java 8 that have nanosecond resolution rather than millisecond. You may think think that using ".999999999" would handle that case, but then you’d be mistaken when handling date-time values from many databases such as Postgres that use microsecond resolution, ".999999".

In the third-party open-source [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, this Half-Open logic is how its [`Interval`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) class works. The beginning is inclusive and the ending is exclusive. This works out nicely. Similarly, calling `plusWeeks(1)` on a `DateTime` to add a week to the first moment of a day gives you the first moment of the 8th day later (see example below).

## Time Zone

The question and other answers ignores the issue of time zone. If you do not specify, you'll be getting the default time zone. Usually better to specify a time zone, using a [proper time zone name](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) (not 3-letter code).

## Joda-Time

Avoid the java.util.Date & Calendar classes bundled with Java. They are notoriously troublesome.

Here is some example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

**CAVEAT**: I have *not* tested of of the below code thoroughly. Just my first take, a rough draft. May well be flawed.

### Standard Week (Monday-Sunday)

The Joda-Time library is built around the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard defines the first day of the week as Monday, last day as Sunday.

If that meets your definition of a week, then getting the beginning and ending is easy.

**UPDATE** As an alternative to the discussion below, see this very clever and very simple one-liner [solution by SpaceTrucker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19997391/642706).

Simply forcing the day-of-week works because Joda-Time assumes you want:

- Monday to be before (or same as) today.
- Sunday to be after (or same as) today.

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

DateTime weekStart = now.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.MONDAY ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime weekEnd = now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY).plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Interval week = new Interval( weekStart, weekEnd );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "weekStart: " + weekStart );
System.out.println( "weekEnd: " + weekEnd );
System.out.println( "week: " + week );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-24T06:29:23.043+01:00
weekStart: 2014-01-20T00:00:00.000+01:00
weekEnd: 2014-01-27T00:00:00.000+01:00
week: 2014-01-20T00:00:00.000+01:00/2014-01-27T00:00:00.000+01:00
```

To see if a date-time lands inside that interval, call the `contains` method.

```
boolean weekContainsDate = week.contains( now );
```

### Non-Standard Week

If that does not meet your definition of a week, you a twist on that code.

```java
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

DateTime weekStart = now.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
if ( now.isBefore( weekStart )) {
    // If we got next Sunday, go back one week to last Sunday.
    weekStart = weekStart.minusWeeks( 1 );
}
DateTime weekEnd = weekStart.plusWeeks( 1 );
Interval week = new Interval( weekStart, weekEnd );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "now: " + now );
System.out.println( "weekStart: " + weekStart );
System.out.println( "weekEnd: " + weekEnd );
System.out.println( "week: " + week );
```

When run…

```
now: 2014-01-24T00:54:27.092-05:00
weekStart: 2014-01-19T00:00:00.000-05:00
weekEnd: 2014-01-26T00:00:00.000-05:00
week: 2014-01-19T00:00:00.000-05:00/2014-01-26T00:00:00.000-05:00
```

Answer (score 3):

First day of week depends on the country.
What makes the calculation fragile, is that one may break the year boundary, and the week number (`Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR`). The following would do:

```
    Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    int firstDayOfWeek = currentDate.getFirstDayOfWeek();

    Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    startDate.setTime(currentDate.getTime());
    //while (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != firstDayOfWeek) {
    //    startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    //}
    int days = (startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 7 - firstDayOfWeek) % 7;
    startDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);

    Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
    endDate.setTime(startDate.getTime());
    endDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
```

One **bug in Calendar** breaks your code, `clone`, seems to simply give the identical object, hence at the end you have identical dates. (Java 7 at least).

Answer (score 1):

```
 DateTime sDateTime = new DateTime(startDate); // My calendar start date
 DateTime eDateTime = new DateTime(date); // the date for the week to be determined

 Interval interval = new Interval(sDateTime, sDateTime.plusWeeks(1));
 while(!interval.contains(eDateTime))
 {
    interval = new Interval(interval.getEnd(), interval.getEnd().plusWeeks(1));
 }
 return interval;
```