# Get weeks of the month depending on week start

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I am using a custom calendar in my app. I have given the users option to select the first day of the week which could be: `Saturday, Sunday, Monday`

I want to get the number of weeks in a month - depending on when the week starts, overriding the default value of week start - `Sunday`.

**Code:**

```
public int getWeeksOfMonth(int year, int month) { 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    int numOfWeeksInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH); 

    return numOfWeeksInMonth;
}
```

Comment: What problems are you getting?? Any unexpected output?? We cannot figure out with just one method..

Comment: Basically you want to know how many weeks does a month have if you say, for example, that a week starts on wednesday instead of sunday? With this in mind, the code you show returns your expected behaviour for the default value (sunday)?.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleTextFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY); //sets first day to monday, for example.
```

In your case you might want to do this:

```
public int getWeeksOfMonth(int year, int month, int weekStart) { 
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month-1);
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(weekStart);
    int numOfWeeksInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH); 

    return numOfWeeksInMonth;
}
```

And call the method with a line such as

```
int weeks = getWeeksOfMonth(2012, 5, Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
```

Comment: @RohitJain setFirstDayOfWeek is not a static method

Answer (score 3):

Try to set the first day of the week first:

[Calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setFirstDayOfWeek%28int%29)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( calendarStart , calendarStop )
```

## Avoid legacy classes

Avoid the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the modern java.time classes.

## java.time

Track the day-of-week by using the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

```
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.MONDAY ;
```

Get the month you are interested in, represented by a [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html). Perhaps the current month. For current month, you must specify the desired/expected time zone as for any given moment the date may vary around the globe by zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.now( z ) ;
```

Get first and last day of the month.

```
LocalDate monthStart = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
LocalDate monthStop = ym.atEndOfMonth() ;
```

Get date for the day-of-week. For that, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html), one provided by the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class (note the plural `s`).

Spans of time in java.time are wisely defined using Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So note how we need to get the date of the desired day-of-week *after* the end of the month. If the end-of-month happened to itself be the desired day-of-week, we need to go past it.

```
LocalDate calendarStart = monthStart.with( TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( firstDayOfWeek ) ) ;
LocalDate calendarStop = monthStop.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( firstDayOfWeek ) ) ;
```

Calculate the number of weeks between.

```
long weeks = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between( calendarStart , calendarStop ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/R0ZAhU).

> firstDayOfWeek: MONDAY
>
> ym: 2017-09
>
> month: 2017-09-01/2017-09-30
>
> calendar: 2017-08-28/2017-10-02
>
> weeks: 5

[image: calendar of month of September 2017 showing calendar starting with Monday August 28 to Monday October 2.]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).