# java - to get the start date and end date of each week for the given month

Tags: java, date, calendar

Following is the code that I am using to calculate the week start date and end date for the given month. 
Assume week start day is MONDAY and week end day is SUNDAY.
For example, JANUARY, 2013 will have 5 weeks.
If the month starts with Sunday - ignore that day

January 2013
first week - 31-Dec-2012 to 06-Jan-2013
second week - 07-jan-2013 to 13-jan-2013
Third week - 14-jan-2013 to 20-jan-2013
fourth week - 21-jan-2013 to 27-jan-2013
fifth week - 28-jan-2013 to 03-Feb-2013

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<String>> weekdates = getNumberOfWeeks(2013, Calendar.JULY);
    for(List<String> weekDatesLoop:weekdates){
        System.out.println("Start day: "+weekDatesLoop.get(0).toString());
        System.out.println("End day: "+weekDatesLoop.get(1).toString());
    }
  }
public static List<List<String>> getNumberOfWeeks(int year, int month) {
        System.out.println("Month Id: "+month);
        month = month-1;
        System.out.println("Month Id: " + month);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        List<List<String>> weekdates = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

        List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
        //int numOfWeeksInMonth = 1;
        while (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
          //System.out.println(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) );

          if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
            weekdates.add(dates);
          }
          else if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.MONDAY) {
            dates = new ArrayList<String>();
            dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
            //numOfWeeksInMonth++;
          }
          c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        if(dates.size() < 2){
          c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
          dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
          weekdates.add(dates);
        }
        System.out.println(weekdates);
        return weekdates;
      }
```

I am still working on this.
Can anyone please help me in fixing this?

Comment: better algorithm: start from day 1 of a month go back till u find a monday, add 6 days, write, add one day, repeat until reaching a sunday after end of month; and a pointer: split your method into smaller methods, the code gets much simpler and more readable if you do it

Comment: @DariuszWawer Thanks. I followed your algorithm and it worked.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the answer with the following code

```
List<List<String>> getNumberOfWeeks(int year, int month) {
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        List<List<String>> weekdates = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
        List<String> dates;
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        while (c.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month) {
                dates = new ArrayList<String>();
              while (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
                c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);
              }
              dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
              c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 6);
              dates.add(format.format(c.getTime()));
              weekdates.add(dates);
              c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        }
        System.out.println(weekdates);
        return weekdates;
      }
```

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 3):

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. This work is much easier now.

## `YearMonth`

The [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class represents a specific month as a whole. Specify the month using the [`Month`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Month.html) enum.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2013 , Month.JANUARY ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

Get the first of the month.

```
LocalDate firstOfMonth = ym.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

## `TemporalAdjuster`

Get the previous Monday, or stay with this date if it is a Monday.

```
TemporalAdjuster ta = TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ;
LocalDate previousOrSameMonday = firstOfMonth.with( ta ) ;
```

Then loop a week at a time.

```
LocalDate endOfMonth = ym.atEndOfMonth() ;
LocalDate weekStart = previousOrSameMonday ; 
do {
    LocalDate weekStop = weekStart.plusDays( 6 ) ;
    System.out.println( "Week: " + weekStart + " to " + weekStop ) ;
    // Set up the next loop.
    weekStart = weekStart.plusWeeks( 1 ) ;
} while ( ! weekStart.isAfter( endOfMonth ) ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DsTLw7).

> Week: Monday, December 31, 2012 to Sunday, January 6, 2013
>
> Week: Monday, January 7, 2013 to Sunday, January 13, 2013
>
> Week: Monday, January 14, 2013 to Sunday, January 20, 2013
>
> Week: Monday, January 21, 2013 to Sunday, January 27, 2013
>
> Week: Monday, January 28, 2013 to Sunday, February 3, 2013

By the way, you might want to learn about, and consider using, the [ISO 860 standard definition of a week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date). And then use the [`YearWeek`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class of the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution may be to not reinvent the wheel and use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) or a similar library. For instance, you can use the [dayOfWeek()](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#dayOfWeek%28%29) function on a `DateTime` to get the information you're after.

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).